# Why did Walter White choose the name Heisenberg?

Tags: breaking-bad

In *Breaking Bad* Walter White uses the name Heisenberg in the meth business.

Why Heisenberg and not some made up name? Was it because the real [Heisenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_Heisenberg) was a scientific genius who used his knowledge for evil? (Werner Heisenberg worked on [an atom bomb project for the Nazis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_nuclear_weapons_program). If he succeeded, then World War 2 would have had a very different outcome.) Is it a reference to some other aspect of Heisenberg?

If this is not mentioned in the TV series, then can you provide quotes from Vince Gilligan or other sources?